# No named modul keras

Tags: python, keras

[image]

Why is this ??, I've tried it many times but still the results are the same. Is there anything I missed in the install package

Answer (score 2):

try  `from tensorflow import keras`

Answer (score 1):

You have launched `python 2.7.18` whilst `keras`, at least according to [its' pypi.org entry](https://pypi.org/project/Keras/) *is compatible with Python 3.6+*. I suggest considering migration to newer version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `pip list`. It seem you are using virtual environment (`base`) while installing keras which is in different directory then where regular python packages is installed.

Type `deactivate` before installing keras. And then install keras again.

Otherwise if you are planning to use TensorFlow, which itself comes with Keras implementation. So just install TF. after `deactivate` command executed.

`pip install tensorflow`

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll try. if it can be used on IDE spyder?

Comment: It will work with any IDE. Please Do mind upvoting and selecting if helped.